# Variable indefinida en un formulario para actualizar un registro

Tags: php, select, bucles, update, actualizacion

En mi formulario  **cada campo debe tener un valor que traigo de un registro** Es decir los campos que tienen valores (como el nombre : pulpo asado)
No lo escribí, si no que el input tiene un valor y eso es lo que se ve.

Asi se ve mi formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en traer el valor de los select(últimos dos campos del formulario)
En el último campo esta este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No sé porque me sale ese error y lo que **quiero es que cada campo incluyendo los select me traigan el valor que pido** Como se ve en el select de unidad de medida.

He intentado eliminar un select y dejar el otro ; al hacer esto el error desaparece, también he intentado cambiar el orden los select, poniendolos en diferentes posiciones del formulario y cuando hay un select en la primera parte, el resto de campos no muestran los valores.

Intenté verificar que trae la variable datos con el codigo
`var_dump($datos);exit;`
y sale este array

```
array(7) { ["categoria"]=> string(7) "Grupo 1" ["medida"]=> string(9) "Kilogramo" ["codigo"]=> string(1) "1" ["nombre"]=> string(14) "Arroz Chinooos" ["unidades_disponibles"]=> string(1) "6" ["fecha_vencimiento"]=> string(10) "2020-09-03" ["fecha_creacion"]=> string(10) "2020-08-20" }
```

Este es el código de mi formulario

```
<?php


require "../includes/conexion.php";

$codigo = $_REQUEST['codigo'];

$consulta_categoria =  mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codigo , nombre  FROM tblcategoria");
$consulta_u_medida =  mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codigo , nombre  FROM tblunidadmedida");

?>
<html>
<body>
    <header class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start  mb-3 ">
            <a href="registro_producto.php" class="btn btn-light  "> Volver </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="titulo display-4 "> ACTUALIZAR PRODUCTO </h1>
    </header>
    <div class="padre d-flex justify-content-between">
        <?php
        $seleccionar = $conexion->query("SELECT c.nombre as categoria, 
        um.nombre as medida , 
        pt.codigo,pt.nombre,pt.unidades_disponibles,
        pt.fecha_vencimiento,pt.fecha_creacion 
        FROM tblproductoterminado as pt INNER JOIN tblunidadmedida as um 
        ON pt.unidad_medida = um.codigo INNER JOIN tblcategoria as c 
        ON pt.categoria = c.codigo WHERE pt.codigo=" . $codigo);
        

        while ($datos = $seleccionar->fetch_assoc()) {

var_dump($datos);exit;


        ?>
            <div class=" row   hijo-1 ">
                <div class="col-12 ">
                    <form action="update_producto.php" method="post">




                        <div class="form-group row">

                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Código:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="codigo" class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $codigo ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Nombre:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?>">
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Fecha creación:</label><br>
                            <input type="date" name="fecha_creacion" class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $datos['fecha_creacion'] ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Fecha de vencimiento:</label><br>
                            <input type="date" name="fecha_vencimiento" class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $datos['fecha_vencimiento'] ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label ">Unidades disponibles:</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="unidades_disponibles" class="col-8 " value="<?php echo $datos['unidades_disponibles'] ?>">
                        </div>




                        <div class="form-group row">

                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label " for="unidad_medida"> Unidad de medida : </label><br>
                            <select name="unidad_medida" class="col-8">

                                <option selected value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['medida'] ?> </option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($consulta_u_medida as $datos) {
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?> </option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>

                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">

                            <label class="col-4 col-form-label " for="categoria">Categoría: </label><br>
                            <select name="categoria" id="categoria" class="col-8">

                                <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['categoria'] ?> </option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($consulta_categoria as $datos) {
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?> </option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>

                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group inline row justify-content-center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Actualizar producto" id="boton" class="btn btn-primary col-6 rounded-pill"><br> <br>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" img hijo border-left border-primary ">
                <img class="img-fluid  " src="../img/modulo producto.png ">
            <?php }  ?>
            </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias !

Comment: comprueba si la query te esta devolviendo un elemento vacio, tal vez sea el causante del error

Comment: No uses comillas simples para los alias de columnas en las instrucciones SQL. Prueba a poner el `SELECT` de este modo: **`SELECT c.nombre as categoria,  um.nombre as medida  .... etc ....`**

Comment: Verifica si `$datos['categoria']` existe.

Comment: @NicolasOñate gracias por la respuesta  puedes explicarme como debo verificar eso porfa ?

Comment: @A. Cedano gracias ya lo hice, pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: @Bicho Gracias, donde y como puedo verificar ello ?

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($datos);` y agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit] para verificar lo que está trayendo en `$datos`. Puede que la consulta venga vacía o esté fallando debido a algún error de sintaxis o a que no hay conexión, etc. Todos esos controles faltan en tu código. No puedes programar de un modo *optimista*, debes ser lo más *pesimista* posible, pensando en todo lo que puede salir mal, para controlarlo. Es así como se crea un código robusto y a prueba de fallos, no siempre las cosas salen bien y la tarea del programador es prever eso y controlarlo.

Comment: como dice @A.Cedano puedes ver lo que contiene la variable `$datos` de esa manera, también puedes saber si estas recogiendo campor en blanco realizando la query en tu motor de base de datos

Comment: Gracias, edité la pregunta.

Comment: Agrégale dentro del while no afuera.

Comment: No estás gestionando bien los errores, es posible que fallara la consulta SQL por cualquier motivo. Tras cualquier consulta, como `$seleccionar = $conexion->query(`, deberías comprobar si la consulta fue bien con un `if ($seleccionar === false) { die($conexion->error); }`. En cuanto a los alias, no necesitas poner comillas en ellos. Por ejemplo, `c.nombre as 'categoria'` podrías ponerlo como `c.nombre as categoria` (sin las comillas).

Comment: Tienes que testear los datos donde existen, en este caso `$datos` está en el `while`, por tanto, el test debe quedar así: `while ($datos = $seleccionar->fetch_assoc()) {  var_dump($datos);`  ...etc ... si ahí te aparece `NULL` entonces tienes un problema con tu conexión o con tu consulta y será hora de que empieces a ser lo más pesimista posible cuando escribas tus programas. ¿Qué puede fallar? ¿Cómo respondo a esos fallos?

Comment: Gracias ! Edité la pregunta he intenté corregir mis errores porfavor revisenla

Comment: El problema es que **estás abriendo varios `foreach` sin necesidad.** Todo el código está dentro del `while` que crea el array `$datos`, entonces puedes evitar esos `foreach` y usar directamente `$datos`.

Comment: Gracias, los **Foreach** son para ejecutar las consultas que estan arriba de la variable **$seleccionar**  que se ejecuta con el while, esos **foreach** antes eran **while** , estan en los **select** para que después de que se me muestre el valor que trae  con el **while** me muestre las otras opciones .